# Using a generic class's property to tell the class's generic type

Tags: typescript

My TypeScript code looks like this:

```js
type TokenType =
    | "A"
    | "B"
    | "C";

class Token<TType extends TokenType> {
    constructor(public readonly type: TType) {}
}


function testing(token: Token<TokenType>) {
    switch (token.type) {
        case "A":
            token;
            // ^? (parameter) token: Token<TokenType>
            handleTypeA(token); // errors
            break;
    }
}

function handleTypeA(token: Token<"A">) {
  // do stuff with the token here...
}
```

I want to use this `switch` statement to be able to narrow the type of `token`, because I know that it's actually `Token<"A">`. Is there some way to do this? Particularly, without using `as` or some sort of predicate function? In my actual use case I have a very long `TokenType` with many options, so I would rather use a `switch` statement and not a ton of `if ... else if ... else` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a type that is an union of Token types for all possible token types:

```
type TokenType =
    | "A"
    | "B"
    | "C";

class Token<TType extends TokenType> {
    constructor(public readonly type: TType) {}
}

type TokenX = Token<"A"> | Token<"B"> | Token<"C">; // <-- HERE
```

then your testing function would work as you expect:

```
function testing(token: TokenX) {
    switch (token.type) {
        case "A":
            token;
            // ^? (parameter) token: Token<"A">
            handleTypeA(token); // NO ERROR NOW
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can distribute the `TokenType` union to a `Token` union (`SomeToken` in the example below) using a self-indexing [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type TokenType =
    | "A"
    | "B"
    | "C";

class Token<TType extends TokenType> {
    constructor(public readonly type: TType) {}
}

type SomeToken = {
    [TType in TokenType]: Token<TType>
}[TokenType];

function handleTypeA(token: Token<"A">) {}

function testing(token: SomeToken) {
    switch (token.type) {
        case "A":
            token;
            handleTypeA(token); // OK
            break;
    }
}
```